# Is there any reason why compiling with the flag -fbounds-check changes the results (output)?

Tags: multithreading, fortran, openmp, indexoutofboundsexception, gfortran

I am trying to parallelize a code using OpenMP. In order to test my results, I compile as following: (my file is called `hecese_OpenMP.f90`)

```
gfortran -O3 -g -fopenmp hecese_OpenMP.f90 -o hecese_OpenMP
```

and execute with:

```
./hecese_OpenMP
```

In this case, I get logical values (temperature values):

```
   0.0000000000000000        783.49759312323954     
   4.9999999999999996E-006   783.97754329856036     
   9.9999999999999991E-006   784.46409277472367     
   1.4999999999999999E-005   784.93610174094374     
   1.9999999999999998E-005   785.40356531164821     
   2.4999999999999998E-005   785.86244125304006     
   2.9999999999999997E-005   786.31543982367702     
   3.4999999999999997E-005   786.76028899490404     
   3.9999999999999996E-005   787.19919935749363     
   4.4999999999999996E-005   787.62967799732780     
   4.9999999999999996E-005   788.05430483965176     
   5.4999999999999995E-005   788.47014285857574     
   5.9999999999999995E-005   788.88020246536769     
   6.4999999999999994E-005   789.28114213978677     
   6.9999999999999994E-005   789.67635992390058     
   7.4999999999999993E-005   790.06216152696709     
   7.9999999999999993E-005   790.44228749976969     
   8.4999999999999993E-005   790.81272956777650     
   8.9999999999999992E-005   791.17754135728615     
   9.4999999999999992E-005   791.53241936895017     
   9.9999999999999991E-005   791.88172053640665     
   1.0499999999999999E-004   792.22084724600575     
   1.0999999999999999E-004   792.55446522757518     
   1.1499999999999999E-004   792.87767333202453     
   1.1999999999999999E-004   793.19545920221628     
   1.2500000000000000E-004   793.50260538260022     
   1.3000000000000002E-004   793.80443633151526     
   1.3500000000000003E-004   794.09540506217127
```

When trying to compile with the flag -fbounds-check as following:

```
gfortran -O3 -g -fbounds-check -fopenmp hecese_OpenMP.f90 -o hecese_OpenMP
```

and executing as usual, I get strange temperature values(illogical):

```
   0.0000000000000000        3.3678051568814173E+080
   4.9999999999999996E-006   2.0735511943440867E+080
   9.9999999999999991E-006   1.3676510585758991E+080
   1.4999999999999999E-005   8.8222276938810882E+079
   1.9999999999999998E-005   5.7108837929115938E+079
   2.4999999999999998E-005   3.6529924583454717E+079
   2.9999999999999997E-005   2.3293108079294771E+079
   3.4999999999999997E-005   1.4700467727884548E+079
   3.9999999999999996E-005   9.2409585880233678E+078
   4.4999999999999996E-005   5.7484421298339787E+078
   4.9999999999999996E-005   3.5604809767646989E+078
   5.4999999999999995E-005   2.1807048749261957E+078
   5.9999999999999995E-005   1.3291540309955299E+078
   6.4999999999999994E-005   8.0025674937017744E+077
   6.9999999999999994E-005   4.7911693804323633E+077
   7.4999999999999993E-005   2.8296567608841817E+077
   7.9999999999999993E-005   1.6599764239864436E+077
   8.4999999999999993E-005   9.5877223899911227E+076
   8.9999999999999992E-005   5.4907601600220782E+076
   9.4999999999999992E-005   3.0867706571011204E+076
   9.9999999999999991E-005   1.7152374444148965E+076
   1.0499999999999999E-004   9.3084530138270176E+075
   1.0999999999999999E-004   4.9628366027261650E+075
   1.1499999999999999E-004   2.5578832649607984E+075
   1.1999999999999999E-004   1.2769186604807401E+075
   1.2500000000000000E-004   6.0034678612971150E+074
   1.3000000000000002E-004   2.6103218948330567E+074
   1.3500000000000003E-004   9.5395112603841788E+073
   1.4000000000000004E-004   2.1614190086226482E+073
   1.4500000000000006E-004  -8.3254384174910055E+072
```

I thought `-fbounds-check` was a debugging flag which adds a check that the array index is within the bounds of the array every time an array element is accessed.
Does it intervene in the computations I make in my code ? As you can see from the results, there is a huge difference between the values obtained from the 2 compilations.
I only added the flag.

Comment: Bounds checking is only one of several ways to detect incorrect memory access, and enabling bounds checking could easily change the memory patterns of illegal access. Please create an example of code we can look at to advise you further (see [mre]).

Comment: that can easily happen if you play with fire (pointers). Try also `-fsanitize=address,null` or `valgrind`.

Comment: @VladimirF when I compiled with `-fsanitize=address,null` , I got this error for the first time: =================================================================
==21042==ERROR: LeakSanitizer: detected memory leaks

Direct leak of 29120 byte(s) in 1 object(s) allocated from:
    #0 0x7fc656018bc8 in malloc (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasan.so.5+0x10dbc8)
    #1 0x55a1da9ba58e in hecese /home/hakim/stage_hecese/OpenMP/hecese_OpenMP.f90:918

SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: 29120 byte(s) leaked in 1 allocation(s).

Comment: Leaks are bad, but you are looking some access to some unintended address.

Comment: Please share a minimal reproducible example. Also try your program without openmp / without `-fopenmp` without more details we cannot answer your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change the compilation options the compiler will perform different optimizations and operations, which occur under the hood.

The most likely case is that you have unsafe access to memory somewhere in your code, likely an overflow